# Should I be afraid to install NVIDIA driver updates?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, updates, nvidia-optimus

im running ubuntu 12.04 lts using nvidia GeForce GT630M
i already installed bumblebee and it works, but after like 2 weeks using it, i got updates like this:

[image]

should i install the updates? im afraid to install it because i recently had bad experience with nvidia driver in ubuntu (like missing unity,  resolution become small) and it took me to uninstalling ubuntu to fix that.. since i already install all the application i need, i dont want to break my system again (which will cause me to reinstall ubuntu to refix system and reinstall all application).

Comment: you should not update unless it is security related as you concern installing update would break you system.

Comment: no i meant the updates i have been doing all the time have never broken my system but the manual nvidia driver install did. i searched google about it and find alot of problem because of installing nvidia updates from update manager/terminal/etc , like this one :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/174471/problems-with-nvidia-driver-after-update?rq=1

Comment: The drivers shouldn't autoupdate normally, but if nvidia-current was updated you should read its description and changelog in details.  It may have a security fix or something.

Comment: Nvidia drivers are particularly notorious for regressions, e.g. an update may break something, the next will fix it but break something else, etc.  If you're happy with the current version, I'd stick with it.